KMS with encryption SDK - how to do envelope encryption?
I am currently using the aws encryption sdk to encrypt and decrypt some of my data (encrypted at rest).
However, when trying to decrypt a lot of the data at once, it is very slow. On inspection, it seems that the SDK is making a HTTP call for each piece of data!
I found a good post on this sub that suggests that there are 2 ways to do this. The latter being envelope encryption, which seems way better for my use case.
However, I cannot find a clear example of how to setup this envelope encryption with the SDK. Ideally I want to just have KMS manage the key that is used to encrypt the data key. Therefore it would only be 1 HTTP call, with the encryption / decryption of the data being handled locally.
Is there a way to do this with the SDK? Or do I need to manually manage this?
here is my code:

import aws_encryption_sdk
import botocore
from aws_encryption_sdk import CachingCryptoMaterialsManager, CommitmentPolicy
from flask import current_app


def get_master_key_provider():
    botocore_session = botocore.session.get_session()
    key_arn = current_app.config["KMS_KEY"]
    kms_kwargs = dict(key_ids=[key_arn])

    if botocore_session is not None:
        kms_kwargs["botocore_session"] = botocore_session

    master_key_provider = aws_encryption_sdk.StrictAwsKmsMasterKeyProvider(
        **kms_kwargs
    )

    return master_key_provider


def generate_cache(
    MAX_CACHE_SIZE=10, MAX_ENTRY_MESSAGES=10, MAX_ENTRY_AGE_SECONDS=60.0
):
    key_provider = get_master_key_provider()
    cache = aws_encryption_sdk.LocalCryptoMaterialsCache(MAX_CACHE_SIZE)

    caching_cmm = CachingCryptoMaterialsManager(
        master_key_provider=key_provider,
        cache=cache,
        max_age=MAX_ENTRY_AGE_SECONDS,
        max_messages_encrypted=MAX_ENTRY_MESSAGES,
    )

    return caching_cmm


class DecryptionSession:
    def __init__(
        self,
        MAX_CACHE_SIZE=10,
        MAX_ENTRY_MESSAGES=10,
        MAX_ENTRY_AGE_SECONDS=60.0,
    ):
        self._caching_cmm = generate_cache(
            MAX_CACHE_SIZE, MAX_ENTRY_MESSAGES, MAX_ENTRY_AGE_SECONDS
        )
        self._client = aws_encryption_sdk.EncryptionSDKClient(
            commitment_policy=CommitmentPolicy.REQUIRE_ENCRYPT_REQUIRE_DECRYPT,
        )

    def decrypt_text(self, ciphertext: str):
        """Decrypts an encrypted piece of text and returns the original text"""
        ciphertext_bytes = bytes.fromhex(ciphertext)
        decrypted_bytes, _ = self._client.decrypt(
            source=ciphertext_bytes, materials_manager=self._caching_cmm
        )

        decrypted_text = decrypted_bytes.decode()
        return decrypted_text

I am using the Python SDK if that makes any difference.

Data key caching needs to start at encryption time. Left to itself, the SDK will create a random data key for each plaintext and wrap that key (round trips the KMS). On decryption, each ciphertext will have a different wrapped key which needs to be unwrapped to the data key (round trips the KMS).
Data key caching works by reusing the same data key for several plaintexts - which takes just one round trip to wrap it. On decryption of several ciphertexts, we can hope that they were encrypted using the same data key. Processing the first ciphertext requires that the data key be unwrapped (round trip) but if subsequent ciphertexts come from the same batch, the cache will already have the unwrapped data key.
Note, however, that data key caching is defeated if you have a different encryption context for two plaintexts (if I remember correctly). (This was a problem in our application.)
To solve this we introduced an intermediate key stored by the application. This 'Raw AES key' ( https://docs.aws.amazon.com/encryption-sdk/latest/developer-guide/use-raw-aes-keyring.html ) was used to encrypt hundreds of plaintexts. (Note that, as stated above, the SDK generated a random data key for each plaintext and wrapped that data key using the intermediate key. So, unlike data key caching, the data key wasn't reused. Also, we were able to use a different encryption context for each plain/ciphertext.)
The intermediate key is, of course, encrypted using the SDK under the KMS key, with the ciphertext of that key stored in the application's database.
On startup, the application loads that encrypted key, decrypts it (rounds trips the KMS) and caches it. It can now encrypt and decrypt freely without any more round trips of the KMS. The downside is that that key is held in memory while the application is running - maybe you wouldn't want to do this in Java where the heap can be dumped. Compare this to normal operation of the SDK where the KMS-based key never leaves the KMS and data keys are sent back and forth to be wrapped and unwrapped.
In summary, to improve KMS performance, you either need to encrypt many plaintexts using a single data key (data key caching) or you can introduce an intermediate key (understanding that this key is held in memory of the application - unlike the "never leaves the KMS" type key.)

Really insightful answer thank you. If I were to use data key caching, is there a way I can tell the SDK to use 1 data key for all data? So on instantiation, a single data key will be generated, and that will be used for all encryption in context?

One more question on raw AES key - if the data key is NOT reused, how does decryption only manage one single round trip? Would it not need to do a round trip for each data key?
Am I right in saying that the raw AES key is used to just manage the data key, then that now decrypted data key (which is done locally opposed to KMS round trip) is used to decrypt the plaintext locally?

Data key caching - the SDK will reuse the same data key (if configured) for plaintexts with the same encryption context, but only for a limited amount of data - it keeps track of the amount of data encrypted with that key and eventually grabs a new key.

When you introduce an intermediate key, each plaintext is encrypted with an ephemeral key just for that plaintext. The ephemeral key is wrapped with the AES key - and stored as normal with the ciphertext (automatically). Encryption is done by generating a random data key, encrypting the plaintext, wrapping the data key. Decryption is done by unwrapping the data key, decrypting the ciphertext. All wrapping and unwrapping is done with the in-memory key - no round trips to KMS except at startup (to decrypt the intermediate key).
